# set header Access-Control-Allow-Origin in plain html

Tags: javascript, html, security, cors, http-headers

I know this can be done through PHP ... languages.

But,
here is the scenario:
I load html files in specific "div" in "current.html" file by following function:

```
$("#dv_sample").load("https://sifr.in/sample_page.html",function(){
    //do my work here ...
});
```

**This works fine.**

I want to use this same function and load "https://sifr.in/sample_page.html" into div, on another (my own)website,
So,
I want to set CORS, **only on this** "https://sifr.in/sample_page.html" file.

I have to set following header in "sample_page.html" (**.html** is important)
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

**How do I set it?

(without PHP or any other language).**

I have tried setting below line in **sample_page.html:**
`<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">`

**But it doesn't work.**

Can JavaScript be useful?

Comment: @jub0bs, so is the answer, just "no"?

Comment: You have to configure CORS on `sifr.in` (even for only the page of interest), but CORS headers cannot be specified in a `meta` tag.